# Prevent my iOS 7 app from upgrading

Tags: ios, upgrade

I want to release a major upgrade of my app, but I need the user to finish all his open task first.

So:

- How can I detect that the upgrade is available and will be installed?
- How can I prevent it until I give an all clear for upgrading?

Comment: You have no control over the update process.

Comment: By upgrade you mean update? I don't think you can ever do that.

Comment: Another approach: Do versioning inside your app. In your updated version, don't enable your new features until the user has finished all his old tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't affect the upgrading process. It is handled outside the scope of your app.